# owasp ESAPI encodeForSQL method to protect SQL injection with Codec DB2Codec

Tags: java, sql-injection, owasp, esapi

I am trying to protect server code from SQL injection.

In order to do so I have used ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL method with Codec  DB2Codec as my database is DB2.

But output of the above method puts extra single quote whenever I have given single quote in the query hence make the query invalid when try to execute the query.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET USER = 'temp' WHERE ID = 247";

    String testmod = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL(new DB2Codec(), test);

    System.out.println(testmod);

}
```

The output of the code is

> UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET USER = ''temp'' WHERE ID = 247

Please find the image as well [image]

Which is invalid sql syntax.

Any suggestion how to solve the problem !!

Comment: I would suggest switching over to prepared statements for sql injection prevention right now when you still can make this decision easily :)

Comment: where did you get the idea that a whole SQL query have to be encoded?

Comment: Ben is a absolutely right. Prepared statements (aka, parameterized queries) should ALWAYS be your first line of defense in combating SQLi. And almost always, that is a sufficient defense. Is there some reason why you think it is not? I would refer you to OWASP's SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet for further defenses. You can find it at: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks @KevinW.Wall, I was just trying to look if any other option is available to protect server side code from SQLi, it looks like the best way is to use Prepared statements. I will move forward with this :)

Comment: The purpose of the SQL encoding methods is to provide an emergency solution shortly after a compromise to allow developers time to redevelop queries to use Prepared Statements.  In this particular case @YourCommonSense is on the correct path as to why this fails to work.  Only encode the exact data to be used.